# Missing Return Value and more commands at ASP.NET Powershell via RemoteRunspace

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, exchange-server

I started a project exchange Powershell via ASP.net in C#.

My code is running but there are some obstacles..

1. How is it possible to use more then one commandlet after another and not use ADDScirpt?
2. Why did a only get back one attribute value for `get-mailbox` ?

I only get the `Displayname`, but no alias or `Servername`.

If I use the `AddScript` with `| Select-Object Displayname,alias`, I get the values as a string chain.

Example Powershell :

```
    set-adserverstettings -viewentireforrest:$true  
    get-mailbox Administrator | fl
```

Result/Output:

```
    Name,Alias,ServerName,ProhibitSendQuota  
    Administrator,admin,ex01,unlimited
```

Visual Studio:

Example ASP.net more than one cmdlet :

```
var command = new Command("get-mailbox");  
command.Parameters.Add("Identity", "Administrator");  
pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Set-ADServerSettings -ViewEntireForest:$true");
pipeline.Commands.Add(command);
```

Result/Output:

```
Nothing/EMPTY/NULL
```

Example ASP.net not all values :

```
pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Get-Mailbox -identity Administrator");
```

Result/Output:

```
Administrator (Global Admin Account)
```

My code:

```
string runasUsername = "admin@abc.at";
string runasPassword = "MyPassword";

System.Security.SecureString ssRunasPassword = new System.Security.SecureString();

foreach (char x in runasPassword)
    ssRunasPassword.AppendChar(x);

PSCredential credentials = new PSCredential(runasUsername, ssRunasPassword);
var connInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://ex01.abc.at/PowerShell"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", credentials);
connInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;

var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connInfo);

string script = @"Set-ADServerSettings -ViewEntireForest:$true
        get-mailbox Administrator";

runspace.Open();
var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);
Collection<PSObject> resultss = pipeline.Invoke();
string str = "";

foreach (PSObject psObject in resultss)
{
    str = str + psObject;
}

runspace.Dispose();
Label1.Text = str;
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Do not pipe to `| Format-Table` and see if that helps.

Comment: No didn't help. `| Format-Table` isnt working.
If i remove `| Format-table` i still didn't get a full result just 'Displayname'.